# How to use double typed maps for remapping in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, floating-point, double, remap

**Problem with `cv::remap()`:**

I am using double values for my image coordinates and want to `cv::remap()` those to create an distorted image.

However, `OpenCV` only allows me to use `CV_32FC1` (`float`) as map type, and not `CV_64FC1` (`double`).

Except for typecasting my `double` values to `float` before remapping and using the float-type maps for `cv::remap()`, is there another way?

**Code Snippet:**

```
Eigen::Vector2d distort(Eigen::Vector2d & pointUndistorted);    

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cv::Mat image, dst;
    image = cv::imread(argv[1], 1);
    Eigen::Vector2d pointUndistorted;
    Eigen::Vector2d pointDistorted;
    int w = image.rows;
    int h = image.cols;
    cv::Mat map1(w,h,CV_64FC1);
    cv::Mat map2(w,h,CV_64FC1);

    for (int wIdx = 0; wIdx < w; ++wIdx)
    {
        for (int hIdx = 0; hIdx < h; ++hIdx)
        {
            pointUndistorted << (double)wIdx / (double)w -0.5, (double)hIdx / (double)h -0.5;
            pointDistorted = distort(pointUndistorted);

            map1.at<double>(wIdx,hIdx) = (pointDistorted[0] + 0.5) * h;
            map2.at<double>(wIdx,hIdx) = (pointDistorted[1] + 0.5) * w;
        }
    }

    cv::remap(image, dst, map1, map2, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
}
```

This gives me the following error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (((map1.type() == (((5) & ((1 << 3) -
>   1)) + (((2)-1) << 3)) || map1.type() == (((3) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) +
>   (((2)-1) << 3))) && map2.empty()) || (map1.type() == (((5) & ((1 << 3)
>   - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) && map2.type() == (((5) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)))) in remap, file
>   /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp,
>   line 1840

Comment: use cv convert routines?

Comment: Why are you using double values instead of floats, when you know you need floats for `remap`?

Comment: @DanMašek I'm using double values cause this feature needs to be compatible with other parts of the software package.

Comment: @Yakk I thought about that, but why won't openCV take my double values? When I am using for in and output the same type, what is the reason that it doesn't accept it?

Comment: "why won't openCV take my double values" -- because the function wasn't designed to work with them. Most likely noone found the extra precision worth the performance cost. OpenCV is open source, so if you really need that functionality, you may remedy it (or perhaps post a feature request).

Comment: And I was answering it, no offence intended. :) You'll find that other functions in OpenCV also restrict the types they support, some colour conversions are not implemented, some functions may not have Python bindings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Yakk for the suggestion:

I hacked a work-around with `map.convertTo(map, CV_32FC1)`, which is working perfectly fine for me.